# ytick pgfplot issue

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have the following latex code but unfortunately cannot get the ytick to be of my choice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=Trail Run \#,
            ylabel=Task completion time,
            xtick={0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20},
            ytick={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
        legend style={
                at={(0.5,0.5)},
                anchor=center}]

        \addplot[smooth,color=black,mark=*]
            plot coordinates {
                (1, 5.372137)
                (2, 5.401571)
                (3, 5.418153)
                (4, 5.409281)
                (5, 5.440709)
                (6, 5.425516)
                (7, 5.366961)
                (8, 5.392147)
                (9, 5.345825)
                (10, 5.366253)
                (11, 5.320773)
                (12, 5.373887)
                (13, 5.338346)
                (14, 5.322246)
                (15, 5.399925)
                (16, 5.349757)
                (17, 5.345629)
                (18, 5.336819)
                (19, 5.364673)
                (20, 5.402730)  
            };
        \addlegendentry{XY at 3x3}

        \addplot[smooth,color=magenta,mark=*]
            plot coordinates {
                (1, 4.349543)
                (2, 4.348597)
                (3, 4.349540)
                (4, 4.348221)
                (5, 4.344659)
                (6, 4.350545)
                (7, 4.345121)
                (8, 4.337458)
                (9, 4.344044)
                (10, 4.349293)
                (11, 4.344615)
                (12, 4.349939)
                (13, 4.346299)
                (14, 4.341717)
                (15, 4.345412)
                (16, 4.351933)
                (17, 4.351421)
                (18, 4.338126)
                (19, 4.345590)
                (20, 4.348072)
            };
        \addlegendentry{YX at 3x3}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

In this case I've specifically changed the legend's position which I didn't really want to. I want the legend to be on south east (which I can do) but I want the ytick to be more like — {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} so I've both the graphs near each other and make terminal '0' as the reference.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi; I've added the required lines of code. Also, added the 'ytick' line of code that I'm having issues with. Thanks.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `ymax=6, ymin=0`?

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you really want to control the min and max y values, then you need to set them `ymax=6, ymin=0`.  Adding these options yields:

[image]